# How to find a file path in a specific directory without knowing the file extension?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to retrieve a file path for a file called `player.#`, where the number is a value from 1-20.  The mounting point in the system is `/media/usb#` and the usb values range from 0-19.  The usb values **do not** match the player values.  After this, I need to store the file extension from the `player.#` to a variable to use later on in the script.

So far, I have tried this:

```
for x in range {0..19}
do
    DATA_DIR=/media/usb"$X"
    PLAYER_FILE_PATH=`find -type f -path $DATA_DIR -name 'player.*' -printf '%f'`
    PLAYER_FILE_ONLY='basename -- "$PLAYER_FILE_ONLY"`
    PLAYER_NUMBER=`echo "${PLAYER_FILE_ONLY##*.}"'
done
```

I am getting a blank return statement, or an error saying the path does not exist.  The file definitely does exist, but I am stumped as to why this is not working.

---

I got it to work.  I didn't realize that the `find` function was so picky about `''` and `""`.  Also, I was being too specific with what I needed so changing my find function to

```
PLAYER_FILE_PATH=`find $DATA_DIR -name "player.*"`
```

fixed the issue!

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus I am currently using MobaXterm.  I am SSHed into an RPi.

Comment: `'player.*'` and `"player.*"` are equivalent. Changing from one to the other wouldn't have made a difference.

Comment: It's better to [post the solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that you only have 1 player.# file. Here is my approach: I am using wildcards instead of the `find` command:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PLAYER_FILE_PATH=/media/usb*/player.*
PLAYER_FILE_ONLY=$(basename $PLAYER_FILE_PATH)
PLAYER_NUMBER=${PLAYER_FILE_ONLY##*.}

echo Player File Path: $PLAYER_FILE_PATH
echo Player File Only: $PLAYER_FILE_ONLY
echo Player Number: $PLAYER_NUMBER
```

Sample output:

```
Player File Path: /media/usb11/player.12
Player File Only: player.12
Player Number: 12
```